# Expected number of unlike pairs when drawing from a set containing two types of items

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Suppose that I have a multiset containing multiple copies of two types of items, such as ${A, A, A, A, B, B}$. Suppose I start drawing random pairs from this set without replacement, such as $AA, AB, AB$, until I have used all of the elements of the set.  How do I calculate the expected number of a certain type of pairing (say $AB$)?

This seems like this would be a problem that would come up in genetics (ie, the probability of getting a certain allele pairing, given separate frequencies of each allele in a large population), but I cannot find anything along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_{AB}(a,b)$ be the expected number of $AB$ pairs if the urn contains $a$ $A$'s and $b$ $B$'s.  So your problem is to compute $E_{AB}(4,2).$  There are $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ ways to draw two letter.  There is 1 way to draw $BB$, 6 ways to draw $AA$ and 8 ways to draw $AB$.  So $$E_{AB}(4,2)= \frac{1}{15}E_{AB}(4,0) + \frac{6}{15}E_{AB}(2,2) + \frac{8}{15}(1+E_{AB}(3,1)).$$  Of course, $E_{AB}(4,0) = 0,$ but you need to continue, computing the remaining terms by the same method, until you get the final answer.

Of course, similar calculations work for the expected number of other pairs.  As a sanity check, if you compute them all, they have to add up to 3, since we always get 3 pairs.

**EDIT** Here are the formulas you asked for.  In what follows, we let $$p_{AA} = \frac{\binom{a}{2}}{\binom{a+b}{2}},p_{BB} = \frac{\binom{b}{2}}{\binom{a+b}{2}},p_{AB} = \frac{ab}{\binom{a+b}{2}}$$ 
Then $$\begin{align}E_{AA}&=p_{AA}(1+E_{AA}(a-2,b))+p_{AB}E_{AA}(a-1,b-1) +p_{BB}E_{AA}(a,b-2)\\E_{BB}&=p_{AA}E_{BB}(a-2,b)+p_{AB}E_{BB}(a-1,b-1) +p_{BB}(1+E_{BB}(a,b-2))\\E_{AB}&=p_{AA}E_{AA}(a-2,b)+p_{AB}(1+E_{AB}(a-1,b-1)) +p_{BB}E_{AB}(a,b-2)\\ \end{align}$$

Now we need some ending conditions.  All the expectations are defined to be $0$ if $a<0, \text{ or } b<0 \text{ or } a+b<2.$  We also have the usual convention for binomial coefficients: if $a<2 \text{ then } \binom{a}{2} = 0.$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am having trouble seeing what the general approach would be---is there a general formula in terms of $a$, $b$, and $N \equiv a+b$?

Comment: If you mean a general formula for the expectation, I feel sure there isn't.  If you mean a recursive formula for computing $E_AB(a,b)$, sure there is.  Do you follow the computations in my answer?  I can add  formulas to the answer, but they won't be much use unless you understand the example.  Feel free to ask me anything about the example.

Comment: Thank you, I see now why this probably has to be done recursively. I am not sure that I see where the $1$ comes from in the diagonal terms like $(1+E_{AA}(a-2,b))$, I would appreciate it if there is a simple explanation

Comment: Sorry to be so long in answering.  I didn't see this until just now.  The $1$ is there because those are the cases in which we've drawn the relevant pair.  In this case, we've drawn $AA,$ so we count an $AA$ pair in our computation of $E_{AA}.$  We have the pair we just drew, plus whatever pairs we will draw in the future.  When we draw $AB$ on the other hand, any $AA$ pairs will have to come from future draws.